# socket: too many open files Error for goroutines in indefinite loop

Tags: for-loop, go, goroutine, datadog

I have a requirement in my program to send metrics to datadog indefinitely (for continuous app monitoring in datadog). The program runs for a while and exits with the error "dial udp 127.0.0.1:18125: socket: too many open files".

```
    func sendData(name []string, channel chan []string) {
      c, err := statsd.New("127.0.0.1:18125")
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
      }

      v := versionDetails()
      tag := "tag:" + v
      final_tag := []string{dd_tags}
      appEpochTimeList := epochTime()
      rate := float64(1)

      for i, app := range name {
        e := c.Gauge(app, float64(appEpochTimeList[i]), final_tag , rate)
        if e != nil {
            log.Println(e)
            channel <- name
        }
        channel <- name
        log.Printf("Metrics Sent !!")
      }
  }
```

The app names are read from a config.toml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `sendData()` function. This function is called in your for loop and has the following line:

```
c, err := statsd.New("127.0.0.1:18125")
```

This line will create a new DataDog client, which uses a Unix socket. This explains your error message.

With every iteration of your loop, a new socket is "allocated". After a sufficient amount of loops no sockets can be opened, resulting in:

> socket: too many open files

To fix this you should create the client only once and pass it to your method as parameter.

```
func sendData(client *statsd.Client, name []string, channel chan []string) {
    // do something with client...
}

func main() {
    client, err := statsd.New("127.0.0.1:18125")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // do something else ...

    for res := range channel {
        go func(client *statsd.Client, appName []string) {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            go sendData(client, appName, channel)
        }(client, res)
    }
}
```

Comment: Or close it after writing data?

Comment: @Bohemian that is probably also an option. But it is not as good for two reasons: unnecessary operations/allocations and reduces testability. If the DataDog is a dependency of the function, you could pass a mock in a test etc

Comment: @Jens I updated the code with the changes. Now it runs for a longer time but exits with the error `panic: runtime error: index out of range`

Comment: @Bohemian Could you please elaborate your point a bit. I am new to Golang. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @ShatabdiPal Great News. Please accept my answer and create a new question with your new problem.

Comment: @Jens I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043901/panic-runtime-error-index-out-of-range-error-for-goroutines-in-indefinite-loop

Comment: @ShatabdiPal I am new to golang too btw. However the idea is not language specific: you open an IO resource, use it, then close it. I haven’t checked the API for statsd, but I would imagine something like `c.close()`

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, close works. I've seen this earlier as well. Either use the same connection or close it and open a new one.